# Solve this simple Linear SDE?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

How do I solve the following BSDE? 
$$ \left\{
\begin{aligned}
dX_t &=(rX_t+\theta Z_t ) \, dt + Z_t \, dW_t \\
X_T &=\xi
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

There appears to be nothing online about this, so maybe its super trivial?

Comment: What is $Z_t$ ?

Comment: $Z_t$ is stochastic too, but only solvable via a martingale representation

Comment: does nobody know this?

Comment: You are aware that there is no way of solving for $X$ without having a description for $Z$?

Comment: $$e^{-rt}X_t=e^{-rT}\xi-\theta\int_t^Te^{-rs}Z_sds-\int_t^Te^{-rs}Z_sdW_s$$

Answer (score 1):

Here we use [Solution to General Linear SDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788853/solution-to-general-linear-sde)

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}X_t = (a(t)X_t+ b(t)) \mathrm{d}t + (g(t)X_t+ h(t))\mathrm{d}B_t 
\end{align*}

for $g=0, a=r,b=\theta Z_{t},h(t)=Z_{t}$

\begin{align*}
X_t = & X_0 e^{ \int_0^t a(s)\mathrm{d}s}+ e^{ \int_0^t a(s)\mathrm{d}s}\left( \int_0^t e^{ -\int_0^s a(r)\mathrm{d}r}b(s) \mathrm{d}s + \int_0^t e^{ -\int_0^s a(r)\mathrm{d}r}h(s) \mathrm{d}B_s\right)\\
= & X_0 e^{ t}+ e^{ t}\left( \int_0^t e^{ -s}\theta Z_{s} \mathrm{d}s + \int_0^t e^{ -s} Z_{s}\mathrm{d}B_s\right).
\end{align*}