# Question on Stochastic Differential Equations with Closed Form Solutions

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Excuse the generality of my question. I'm new to the topic of stochastic processes and want to know is their a general form of SDEs that have closed-form solutions?

I saw that $dX_t = dt + 2\sqrt{X_t}dW_t$ has a closed form solution, which can be obtained through Ito's Formula.

Comment: Apart from the ones obtained directly via Ito's lemma, you may want to check my answer for the closed form solutions of SDEs of the form $
\mathrm{d}X_t = (a(t)X_t+ b(t)) \mathrm{d}t + (g(t)X_t+ h(t))\mathrm{d}B_t 
$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788853/solution-to-general-linear-sde/1789044#1789044 it is obtained by integrating factor method. I might try to write an answer to you question later on.

Comment: Are you happy with the below answer?

Answer (score 2):

A linear SDE is of the form 
$$(\star) \qquad \mathrm{d}X_t = (a(t)X_t+b(t))\mathrm{d}t + (g(t)X_t + h(t))\mathrm{d}B_t,$$
where $a$, $b$, $g$, $h \colon \mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Its closed form solution might be obtain via integrating factor method as it has been indicated in my comment.

There is a class of reducible SDEs which may be transformed to the form $(\star)$. 
The results on transforming the SDEs of the form
$$(\dagger) \qquad \mathrm{d}X_t = \mu(t, X_t)\mathrm{d}t + \sigma(t, X_t)\mathrm{d}B_t,$$
where $\mu$, $\sigma \colon \mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, into $(\star)$ can be found in 
Chapter 18, section 18.5 of the book R. L. Schilling and L. Partzsch, "Brownian Motion. An Introduction to Stochastic Processes", De Gruyter.

They use Ito's lemma for a transformed $X_t$, that is, $Z_t=f(t, X_t)$, where $f$ is invertible in the second coordinate. 
Given some conditions on the coefficients $\mu$ and $\sigma$ you may transform $(\dagger)$ into $(\star)$-type, namely
$$\mathrm{d}Z_t = (a(t)Z_t+b(t))\mathrm{d}t + (g(t)Z_t + h(t))\mathrm{d}B_t.$$
The last SDE can be solved explicitly, and so $X_t = f^{-1}(t, Z_t)$. Now depending on the conditions imposed on the coefficients $\mu$ and $\sigma$ you may obtain the explicit form of $f$.

The second reference is  Chapter 4, sections 4.2 and 4.3 in P.E. Kloeden and E. Platen, "Numerical Solution of Stochastic Differential Equations", Springer. I preferred Schilling's book.