# Solve the SDE $d X_{t} = \alpha X_t dt + \gamma X_t dW_t - \phi X_t^2 dt$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I would like to solve a SDE similar to the GBM but with an additional term. Generally, the process I'm looking for should have the following recursive form:
$$ \frac{dX_t}{X_t} = \alpha dt + \gamma dW_t - \phi X_t dt, $$
$$ d X_{t} = \alpha X_t dt + \gamma X_t dW_t - \phi X_t^2 dt. $$

I have attempted solving the SDE without success using Ito's Lemma when $f(X_t) = ln(X_t) $
$$ d ln(X_t) = \frac{1}{X_t} dX_t - \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{X_t^2} (dX_t)^2 $$
$$ d ln(X_t) = \frac{dX_t}{X_t} - \frac{1}{2X_t^2} (\gamma X_t dW_t)^2 $$
$$ d ln(X_t) = \frac{d X_t}{X_t} - \frac{1}{2} \gamma^2 dt $$
$$ \frac{d X_t}{X_t} = d ln(X_t) + \frac{1}{2} \gamma^2 dt $$

and when $ f(X_t) = X_t^{-1} $  (**EDIT**: fixed some mistakes below)
$$ d (X_t^{-1}) = - \frac{1}{X_t^2} dX_t + \frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{X_t^3} (dX_t)^2 $$
$$ d (X_t^{-1}) = - \frac{1}{X_t^2} (\alpha X_t dt + \gamma X_t dW_t - \phi X_t^2 dt) + \frac{1}{X_t^3} (\gamma X_t dW_t)^2 $$
$$ d (X_t^{-1}) = - \alpha X_t^{-1} dt - \gamma X_t^{-1} dW_t + \phi dt + \gamma^2 X_t^{-1} dt $$
$$ d f_t = \phi dt + (\gamma^2 - \alpha) f_t dt - \gamma f_t dW_t $$
$$ d f_t = (\phi + \gamma^2 f_t - \alpha f_t) dt - \gamma f_t dW_t $$

By substituting the result from the first attempt with Itô's Lemma into the original SDE I obtained
$$ d ln(X_t) + \frac{1}{2} \gamma^2 dt = \alpha  dt + \gamma  dW_t - \phi X_t dt $$
$$ ln(X_t) - ln(X_0) = (\alpha - \frac{1}{2} \gamma^2) t + \gamma  W_t - \phi \int_{0}^{t} X_t dt $$
$$ ln(X_t) + \phi \int_{0}^{t} X_t dt = ln(X_0) (\alpha - \frac{1}{2} \gamma^2)t + \gamma  W_t. $$

**EDIT**: The result from the second attempt with Itô's Lemma might be used in the same way as here https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/50485/solve-the-following-sde-mathrmdx-t-ab-x-t-mathrmdt-c-x-t-mat and maybe here [How to solve the following SDE: $\mathrm{d}X_t = a(b-X_t) \mathrm{d}t + c X_t \mathrm{d}W_t$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3492431/how-to-solve-the-following-sde-mathrmdx-t-ab-x-t-mathrmdt-c-x-t-m)

**EDIT**: <strike>How should I proceed?</strike>

Comment: You have a little mistake, note that $(dX_t)^2 = (\gamma X_t)^2dt$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Simplified that line but couldn't find the mistake. Is there a mistake still?

Comment: The equation you are considering has been extensively studied in population dynamics and systems ecology. It is a stochastic logistic equation or . With this you should be able to find what you are looking for; e.g. http://www.numdam.org/article/RSMUP_2001__106__165_0.pdf

Comment: here is another mistake: the Ito derivative for the second fucntion is incorrect; the second derivative should be multiplied by 1/2... I did not check more details

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the mistake and applied your answer. Now we only have different signs.

Comment: Great! I have editted the sign :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ln$ is not helping you here. Use $f(x)=x^{-1}$ to obtain with Ito's Lemma that $$df=-(\alpha f-\gamma^2 f-\phi)dt - \gamma f dW,$$
which is linear and admits a closed form solution. Once you obtain the solution, you have $x = \frac{1}{f}$.