# Solution of SDE that is almost geometric

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let the SDE be defined by
$$dS_t=\frac{l-S_t}{\tau} dt+mS_t dB_t$$

I tried solving it using the given general solution on wikipedia page with
$c_t= \frac{l}{\tau}$, $a(t)=\frac{-1}{\tau}$, $m=b(t)$, $d(t)=0$. Then $\Phi$ equals
$$\exp\left( \frac{t}{\tau} - \frac{m^2t}{2}  +m W_t\right)$$
and so
$$S_t=-\tau S_0\exp\left( \frac{t}{\tau} - \frac{m^2t}{2}  +m W_t\right)-\tau S_0e^{-t/\tau}$$

Is this correct? where can I read more about this type of SDE?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation

Answer (score 1):

You can use the general formula from here [Solution to General Linear SDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788853/solution-to-general-linear-sde) for $dX_t = \big( a(t) X_t + b(t) \big) dt + \big( g(t) X_t  \big) dB_t,$

\begin{align*}
X_t =&  \exp\left( t\left( \frac{\ell}{\tau}- \frac{1}{2\tau^{2}}\right)  + \frac{-1}{\tau}B_{t}\right) \\ &\cdot \left(X_0+ \int_0^{t} \frac{\ell}{\tau}\exp\left( -s \left( \frac{\ell}{\tau}- \frac{1}{2\tau^{2}}\right) + \frac{1}{\tau}B_{s}\right)\mathrm{d}s\right).
\end{align*}