# Probability distribution of the solution of an SDE

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider a general linear SDE,
$$
dX_t = (a(t)X_t+b(t))dt+(g(t)X_t+h(t))dW_t
$$
an explicit solution to this has been given in detail here:
[Solution to General Linear SDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788853/solution-to-general-linear-sde)
The solution is written as:
$$
X_t = Y_t \left( X_0 + \int_0^t (b(s)-h(s)g(s)) Y^{-1}_s ds + \int_0^t h(s) Y^{-1}_s dW_s \right)
$$
Here $Y_t$ is the solution to the homogeneous case,
$$
Y_t = \exp \left( \int_0^t (a(s)-g^2(s)/2) ds + \int_0^t g(s) dW_s \right)
$$

What I would like to understand is exactly how to get the probability distribution of $X_t$. In particular, I can't see how to solve the integrals that contain $Y^{-1}_s$