# Cross-covariance term of linear stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, covariance, stochastic-differential-equations, noise

Consider the following scalar linear differential equation:
$$
\dot x(t) = c x(t) + w(t),\ \ \ x(0)\in\mathbb{R},
$$
where $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $w(t)$ is a white noise process with $\mathbb{E}[w(t)]=0$ and $\mathbb{E}[w(t)w(s)]=\sigma^2\delta(t-s)$.

> **My question.** What is the value of the cross-covariance term $\mathbb{E}[x(t)w(t)]$?

*My (heuristic) attempt.* The state evolution can be written as
$$
x(t) = e^{ct} x(0) +\int_{0}^t e^{c(t-\tau)} w(\tau) \mathrm{d}\tau.
$$
Hence,
$$
\mathbb{E}[x(t)w(t)] = e^{ct} \mathbb{E}[x(0)w(t)] + \int_{0}^t e^{c(t-\tau)} \mathbb{E}[w(\tau)w(t)] \mathrm{d}\tau = \sigma^2 \int_{0}^t e^{c(t-\tau)} \delta(t-\tau) \mathrm{d}\tau.
$$
The last integral contains a Dirac's delta "function" centered at $t$. But $t$ is also the upper integral limit, so, in some sense, we should consider "half" of the effect of the Dirac's delta, yielding $\mathbb{E}[x(t)w(t)]=\sigma^2/2$.

My argument is totally heuristic and I would like to know if there is a formal way to derive the value of $\mathbb{E}[x(t)w(t)]$. I'm also aware that the definition of white noise, although widely used in physics and engineering, is mathematically tricky and one should always work with the integral of the white noise (i.e., a Wiener process). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your equation is a linear SDE, the general solution has been discussed:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788853/solution-to-general-linear-sde

Comment: Also note that the result depends on whether you use Ito or Stratonovich formulation for the stochastic integral. Your heuristic argument is more similar to Stratonovich formulation.

Comment: @WHLin: Thanks for your comments. I'm not familiar with Ito/Stratonovich formulations, could you please elaborate a bit more and/or point me to some references?

Comment: This is known as "Ito-Stratonivich dilemma", where the interpretation of noise is different. Depending on the system used, one may be more nature to use than the other. In finance or other time-series analysis, usually Ito is more natural. In physics, sometime Stratonovich is more natural (but there are also exceptions).

Comment: @WHLin: Thanks, so, loosely speaking, Ito and Stratonovich use different conventions for the integral of a delta function centered at one of the integral limits?

Comment: @WHLin , well in this case the diffusion does not depend on the solution, so the Stratonovich correction term is equal to 0, meaning that Ito and Stratonovich interpretations coincide