# Solving Non-linear OU Process

Tags: nonlinear-system, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm hoping to find some guidance on solving the following non-linear SDE in distribution. Meaning the distribution of $x_{t + \Delta t} | x_t$ where $x_t = [y_t, z_t]^\prime$.

$ \left[ \begin{array}{c} dy_t \\ dz_t \\ \end{array}\right] \sim \left[ \begin{array}{c} \theta_y \left( \alpha - y_t \right) + \zeta_0 z_t + \zeta_1 z_t^2 \\ -\theta_z z_t \\ \end{array} \right]dt + \left[ \begin{array}{c} \sigma_y & 0  \\ 0 & \sigma_z \\ \end{array}\right] dW_t$

where $W_t$ is a Wiener process.

If it simplifies things, what I am ultimately hoping to deduce is the conditional distribution, $y_{t+\Delta t} | z_{t + \Delta t}, y_t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming $dW_{t}=(dW_{t}^{1},dW^{2}_{t})$.
This is basically solving a linear process. First we solve the Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process $z_t$ equation to get

$$\large z_{t}= \frac{\sigma_{z}}{\sqrt{2\theta_{z}}} e^{-\theta_{z} t} W^{2}(e^{2 \theta_{z} t})$$

(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process#Properties_of_sample_paths).

Now you are just left with a linear SDE

$$dy_{t}=(ay_{t}+b(t))dt+\sigma_{y}dW^{1}(t),$$

for $b(t):=\theta_y  \alpha  + \zeta_0 z_t + \zeta_1 z_t^2 $ and $a:=-\theta_{y}\alpha$,  which can be solved as here [Solution to General Linear SDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788853/solution-to-general-linear-sde)

\begin{align*}
Y_t = & Y_0 e^{ at}+ e^{ at}\left( \int_0^t e^{ -as}b(s) \mathrm{d}s + \int_0^t e^{ -as}\sigma_{y} \mathrm{d}B_s\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.

Comment: While the solution is correct, it does not get at how to solve $\int_0^t z_s ds$ or $\int_0^{t} z_s^2 ds$. These are the hard part of the question.

Comment: @hipHopMetropolisHastings Yes, it does.  From the second equation we get a concrete $z(t)$
$$\large z_{t}= \frac{\sigma_{z}}{\sqrt{2\theta_{z}}} e^{-\theta_{z} t} W^{2}(e^{2 \theta_{z} t}).$$

Then we simply define $b(t)$ to contain that $z(t)$ and $z^{2}(t)$ which are deterministic because $W^{2}$ is independent of $W^{1}$.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand the $W^2(\cdot)$ notation. Shouldn't $z_t$ be an Ito process? Is this related to the fact an Ito Integral can be expressed as a time-change Wiener process? Thanks!

Comment: @hipHopMetropolisHastings Yes, exactly.