# How do you know if something satisfies a Stochastic Differential Equation?

Tags: calculus, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I often come across similar statements:

- Let $X_t$ be a stochastic process that **satisfies** the stochastic differential equation:
  $$dX_t = \mu_t dt + \sigma_t dB_t$$

Where

- $B_t$ is a Weiner process
- $\mu_t$ , $\sigma_t$ are deterministic functions of time.

**My Question:** What does it actually mean to "satisfy" a stochastic differential equation?

It seems to me that these are all just definitions. We are defining $X_t$ such that the derivative of $X_t$ with respect to time is $dX_t = \mu_t dt + \sigma_t dB_t$.  Therefore, it is satisfied by definition. We have chosen $X_t$ such that its derivative satisfies $\mu_t dt + \sigma_t dB_t$.

Thus, is the word "satisfy" really necessary here?

**Could the above statement simply have been written as:** Let $X_t$ be a stochastic process such that: $dX_t = \mu_t dt + \sigma_t dB_t$

**Or does "satisfying a stochastic differential equation" have some other criteria that need to be met?**

Thanks!

Comment: What would you say to a deterministic function $x(t)$ satisfying the ODE $x'(t) = f(x, t)$? Seems no different, no? SDEs are a bit more delicate.

Comment: It means the following equality of stochastic integrals for all $t \geq 0$: $$\int_{0}^{t}dX_s = \int_{0}^{t}\mu_s \,ds + \int_{0}^{t}\sigma_s \,dB_s.$$ Note the left hand side is $X_t - X_0$.

Comment: @SeanRoberson: thank you so much for your reply! can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @Mason: thank you so much for your reply! Is this equality that you have posted referred to as Ito's Lemma?

Comment: @stats_noob No, I just wrote what it means to satisfy that SDE.

Comment: @Mason: thank you for your reply! does this equality have a specific name? is it only true for stochastic integrals? example if Xt and Bt were not stochastic processes, would this equality still be expected to hold?

Comment: Whether the equality holds or not depends on what the values of $X$, $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are. If you have $\mu$ and $\sigma$ already, then that equation defines the process $X$. It's a trivial SDE for $X_t$.

Comment: It is "Wiener", like a man from Vienna, Wien. A "Weiner" is someone feeling sad and shedding tears. People producing "Wein", wine, are called "Winzer", thus not the same word.

Answer (score 1):

First to be clear, the process

$$X_t =x_{0}+ \int_{0}^{t}\mu_s ds + \int_{0}^{t}\sigma_s dB_s$$

is called an [Itô process](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_process). So I agree "satisfying..." doesn't make much sense because $X_{t}$ is already given by the above integrals. It is akin to calling $f'(x)=0, f(0)=a$ an ODE, which has trivially the solution $f(x)=a$.
It is not really thought of as [differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_diffusion) where one tries to identify $X_{t}$ from a recursive-type SDE equation

$$dX_{t}=\mu(t,X_{t})dt+\sigma(t,X_{t})dB_{t}$$

eg. see [Solution to General Linear SDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788853/solution-to-general-linear-sde).

Comment: @ Thomas Kojar: thank you so much for your answer!