# How to prove unique solvability of an SDE?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

I have a stochastic differential equation of the type:
$$ dX(t) = \mu(t) X(t)dt + \sigma(t) X(t) dW(t) \tag{1}
$$
However, my $\mu(t)$ is a complicated function of $t$ as well as $W(t)$, somewhat like:

$$ \mu(t) = t \cdot a(t) + b(t) + \sigma W(t) \tag{2}
$$

I feel like $W(t)dt$ that I get by substituting $(2)$ into $(1)$ doesn't look "right". And I'm not sure how to get the $X(t)$ from that.
**Edit** What I mean, is that my equation $(1)$ becomes:
$$ dX(t) = (t \cdot a(t) + b(t))X(t)dt + \sigma W(t)X(t)dt + \sigma(t) X(t) dW(t) \tag{3}
$$
My questions are:

1. Assuming that I obtain a $X(t)$, does that single-handedly prove that $(1)$ is uniquely solvable? I am not sure what conditions will demonstrate that something is uniquely solvable.
2. Is the $ W(t)dt $ term that I get in equation $(3)$ sensible?

Comment: There is a lot of theory about uniqueness of solutions to SDEs. Check Chapter 5 of Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus by Karatzas. In general, it turns out that if your functions mu and sigma are Lipschitz, then this is typically enough to guarantee some sort of uniqueness

Comment: For the second question, yes, $W(t)dt$ is perfectly sensible.  The paths of $W$ are continuous, so $\int_0^t W(s)ds$ is even defined pathwise.

Answer (score 1):

The equation

$$ dX(t) = \left[(t \cdot a(t) + b(t)+ \sigma W(t)\right] X(t)dt + \sigma(t) X(t) dW(t)=\mu(t)X(t)dt + \sigma(t) X(t) dW(t)
$$
is a linear equation and it has a general solution give here [Solution to General Linear SDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788853/solution-to-general-linear-sde), and to be clear all you need from these various functions is continuity.